# Bigquery RegEx: "Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?="

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I tried to extract a value from the key-values in Bigquery.

The input is:`{"from":"bookmark","video_category":6,"video_id":22719,"content_ownership":"owner"}`, then I use regex101 to construct the regex, so I get this `r'(?:video_id":)(.*?)(?=\,|$)'`

[RegEx input in regex101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soco3.png)

Then, I tried to implement it on Bigquery but it raised `"Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?="`

[RegEx implementation in Bigquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOsgW.png)

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input data is JSON, then you can try **json_extract_scalar** function:

```
with cte as
(
  select '{"from":"bookmark","video_category":6,"video_id":22719,"content_ownership":"owner"}' as data
)
select  json_extract_scalar(t.data, "$.video_id") as video_id
from    cte t
```

Regarding to REGEXP_EXTRACT. BigQuery [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) says:

> Note: BigQuery provides regular expression support using the re2 library; see that documentation for its regular expression syntax.

RE2 library [docs](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) says:

> (?=re)    before text matching re (**NOT SUPPORTED**)

Comment: wow thanks, sir! I never thought to use json_extract, regex is a bit overkill

Comment: This answer solved my problem but not the issue I'm experiencing. I still wonder why my RegEx is not working on Bigquery

Comment: @Amethyst, added info about REGEXP_EXTRACT.